# find the matrix $ P $ such that $ \ rref(A)=PA \ $ .

Tags: matrices

Consider the matrix $ A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 1& 2& 2 & 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 & 0 & -4 & 0 & -5 \\ -2 & -2 & 1 & -6 & 1 & -6   \end{bmatrix} $ .

Find row reduced echelon form $ \ rref(A) \ $ .

Also find the matrix $ P $  such that $ \ rref(A)=PA \ $ .

**Answer:**

I have found $ \ rref(A) \ $ after a long calculation which is given below:

$ rref(A)= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0&0&0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0& \frac{5}{2} \\ 0&0&1&0&0& \frac{1}{2} \\ 0&0&0&1 &0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 & 1 & -\frac{3}{2} \end{bmatrix} $

**But  how to find the matrix $ P \ $ ?**

**Is there any help ?**

Comment: Did you apply only  row operations?

Comment: Yes , only row operations .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you applied row operations, you must know that each row operation can be obtained by pre-multiplying $A$ by an *elementary operation $5\times5$ matrix*, say $R_i$, and that, when you've obtained the R.R.E.F. of $A$ after $n$ steps, you have pre-multiplied by $R_nR_{n-1}\dotsm R_1=P$. Similarly, when you do column operations, you *post*-multiply by  elementary operation  matrices.

Now oberve tha tif you apply the same operations on the $5\times 5$ matrix $I_5$, you pre-multiply it likewisee, and that
$$R_nR_{n-1}\dotsm R_1I_5=PI_5=P.$$
So all you have to do is apply exactly  the same row operations to the unit matrix: $P$ is the transformed matrix.